# How to access Apache website by public-ip with server name?

Tags: apache

I've installed vanilla at Ubuntu server with `public-ip` by the steps at https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-vanilla-forum-on-ubuntu-16-04

Then config `/etc/apache2/sites-available/forum.example.com.conf` as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName forum.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vanilla
    <Directory /var/www/vanilla>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I can access `http://public-ip` at browser, but the result is `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page`.

How can I access the installed vanilla at the browser? Should I make any change to the `forum.example.com.conf`?

Answer (score 0):

If the request doesn't match a virtual host, Apache will serve files from the top level (not inside a <VirtualHost> block) DocumentRoot config value.

```
#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

I don't know Ubuntu well but I'd guess this is in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf. You can change this to /var/www/vanilla to serve your forum instead of the default page.

Alternatively you could rename / delete the existing /var/www/html and make it a symlink to /var/www/vanilla: then Apache would pick up the forum files without any config change.

Or if you just want to set up access for yourself then you can add the DNS name to your hosts file (/etc/hosts on Linux, \Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows)

```
forum.example.com AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD
```

and then you can use forum.example.com in your browser as normal, which will send the 'Host' header so Apache will match the virtual host, even though this isn't configured as public DNS.